# AttributeError: 'RegexpReplacer' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

as defining the class(RegexpReplacer) i found the attribute error and i didn't get the solution for this problem. the code is given bellow and also the error:

```
import re
replacement_patterns = [
(r'won\'t', 'will not'),
(r'can\'t', 'cannot'),
(r'i\'m', 'i am'),
(r'ain\'t', 'is not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ll', '\g<1> will'),
(r'(\w+)n\'t', '\g<1> not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ve', '\g<1> have'),
(r'(\w+)\'s', '\g<1> is'),
(r'(\w+)\'re', '\g<1> are'),
(r'(\w+)\'d', '\g<1> would')
]
class RegexpReplacer(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
        self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]
        def replace(self, text):
                         s = text
                         for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
                             s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
                             return s
replacer=RegexpReplacer()
print(replacer.replace("can't is a contradicton"))
```

i found the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 print(replacer.replace("can't is a contradicton"))
AttributeError: 'RegexpReplacer' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

please if anyone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` method is buried inside the `__init__`, you have to correct the indentation:

```
import re
replacement_patterns = [
(r'won\'t', 'will not'),
(r'can\'t', 'cannot'),
(r'i\'m', 'i am'),
(r'ain\'t', 'is not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ll', '\g<1> will'),
(r'(\w+)n\'t', '\g<1> not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ve', '\g<1> have'),
(r'(\w+)\'s', '\g<1> is'),
(r'(\w+)\'re', '\g<1> are'),
(r'(\w+)\'d', '\g<1> would')
]
class RegexpReplacer(object):
    def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
        self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]
    def replace(self, text):
         s = text
         for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
             s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)
         return s
replacer=RegexpReplacer()
print(replacer.replace("can't is a contradicton"))
```